# Delphi Emulate Keys/Mouse To a Specific window

Tags: delphi

I was wondering how to target a specific window with key strokes/mouse clicks anyone able to help?

Comment: Before we can help, I think you need to clarify exactly what your question is.

Comment: Ok well... I have a Window a specific window no matter where the window is on the screen I want to be able to emulate a mouse click on a button inside the window

Comment: It might be easier to post a WM_COMMAND or BN_CLICKED message to the window handle of the button.

Answer (score 3):

how to search for a 'window' in the OS, if the OS is windows:

```
function FindWindowExtd(partialTitle: string): HWND;
var
  hWndTemp: hWnd;
  iLenText: Integer;
  cTitletemp: array [0..254] of Char;
  sTitleTemp: string;
begin
  hWndTemp := FindWindow(nil, nil);
  while hWndTemp <> 0 do begin
    iLenText := GetWindowText(hWndTemp, cTitletemp, 255);//search after the partial name
    sTitleTemp := cTitletemp;
    sTitleTemp := UpperCase(copy( sTitleTemp, 1, iLenText));
    partialTitle := UpperCase(partialTitle);
    if pos( partialTitle, sTitleTemp ) <> 0 then
      Break;
    hWndTemp := GetWindow(hWndTemp, GW_HWNDNEXT);
  end;
  result := hWndTemp;
end;
```

here you have how to send mouse clicks to a 'window'

http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/a/mouseadvanced.htm

how to send keystrokes to another application from Delphi

http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2004/a/bltip1104_3.htm

if you want something else then modify your question

Answer (score 3):

(Regarding your comment to your question) If the button is a standard [`BUTTON` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), find its handle and send a [`BM_CLICK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to it (take note of the remarks in the documentation for when the dialog is not active).